# Systemback errors - 1st errno:17, and now a bunch of errno: 2's

Tags: systemback

This all started when systemback could not create restore points..after doing some research, I attemepted the commands to remove .gvfs...after doing that, I got another error that the /Desktop/.desktop symlink could not be cloned...

(.gvfs, .dbus, and .cache/dconf in home directory had permission denied...)

The errors are being shown by running the

code: DBGLEV=3 systemback-sustart command

and then attempting to create a new restore point (there are 2 existing restore points, and 1 highlighted restore point)

Im worried that I will just be deleting directory after directory...is there something corrupted that can be fixed, or should I get my user data (not a huge amount) and rebuild?

Here is the command and output:

user1@uw1:~$ `DBGLEV=3 systemback-sustart`

Systemback

```
 Version: 1.8.402_05.16.2016_Qt5.5.1_GCC5.3.1_amd64
 Compilation date and time: May 16 2016 11:15:56
 Installed files: /etc/xdg/autostart/sbschedule-kde.desktop
                  /etc/xdg/autostart/sbschedule.desktop
                  /usr/bin/systemback
                  /usr/bin/systemback-cli
                  /usr/bin/systemback-sustart
                  /usr/lib/systemback/libsystemback.so
                  /usr/lib/systemback/libsystemback.so.1
                  /usr/lib/systemback/libsystemback.so.1.0
                  /usr/lib/systemback/libsystemback.so.1.0.0
                  /usr/lib/systemback/sbscheduler
                  /usr/lib/systemback/sbsustart
                  /usr/lib/systemback/sbsysupgrade
                  /usr/share/applications/systemback-kde.desktop
                  /usr/share/applications/systemback.desktop
                  /usr/share/systemback/efi-amd64.bootfiles
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_ar_EG.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_ca_ES.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_cs.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_da_DK.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_de.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_en_GB.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_es.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_fi.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_fr.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_gl_ES.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_hu.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_id.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_pt_BR.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_ro.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_ru.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_tr.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_uk.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_zh_CN.qm
 Operating system: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
 Mounted filesystems: /dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=order
                      ed 0 0
                      /dev/loop0 /snap/core/1287 squashfs ro,relatime 0 0
                      /dev/loop1 /snap/vlc/4 squashfs ro,relatime 0 0
                      /dev/loop3 /snap/core/1337 squashfs ro,relatime 0 0
                      /dev/loop2 /snap/core/1264 squashfs ro,relatime 0 0
 System language: en_US
 Translation: -



An error occurred while cloning the following symbolic link:

  /home/user1/Desktop/.desktop

 Target symlink:

  /home/Systemback/.S00_2017-03-08,11.06.42/home/user1/Desktop/.desktop

 /home/user1/Desktop/.desktop
  f rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 2049 174B
 /home/user1/Desktop
  d rwxr-xr-x - 1000 1000 2049 -
 /home/user1
  d rwxr-xr-x - 1000 1000 2049 -
 /home
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2049 -

 /home/Systemback/.S00_2017-03-08,11.06.42/home/user1/Desktop/.desktop
  -
 /home/Systemback/.S00_2017-03-08,11.06.42/home/user1/Desktop
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2049 -
 /home/Systemback/.S00_2017-03-08,11.06.42/home/user1
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2049 -
 /home/Systemback/.S00_2017-03-08,11.06.42/home
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2049 -
 /home/Systemback/.S00_2017-03-08,11.06.42
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2049 -
 /home/Systemback
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 1000 2049 -
 /home
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2049 -

 Errno: 2
```

is this what you were looking for?

Comment: hey folks - did I add the appropriate info?  Im still getting SystemBack restore point errors :(

Comment: Also edit in the output of `sudo lsb_release -a` , `apt-cache policy systemback` and what exactly you mean by "attempted to remove .gvfs"  Thank you.